# Managing various versions of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am currently ingesting data from multiple sources. Some of the sources that I am ingesting from have a CountryCode whereas some sources only have the CountryName - all the sources do not conform to the same standard.

I then have a dimCountry table which the source tables should look up to. If there are new Countries, then the dim table should be updated.

However, because there is no standard put in place for all the sources (such as some sources not having CountryCode while others only have the Country name) the dim table could have a country name such as United States of America, whereas the data from source could have the country name as 'USA'.

How do I compare the source data with my dim table in such a manner that it will pick up that USA = United States of America without having to hard code any values?

I would really appreciate any help on this.

Mapping example:

| ID | Source | DimensionValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USA | United States of America |

Questions based on using a mapping table:

1. If I use a mapping table, how would it be updated automatically?
2. How would my dim table and mapping table interact?
3. Would the mapping table interact with my fact tables?

Comment: You need a lookup table. To a database `'USA'` and `'United States of America'` are *completely* different values. You'll need to create a table which maps your various different values to your standardised one.

Comment: @Larnu I have updated the question with a mapping table. Would it be something similar to the table I have in the question? Where I map the value from source and the value from the dimension table? If I use a mapping table, how would it be updated automatically?